# Faceting Not Working Within Dataset - Einstein Analytics

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, saql, facet

I am editing a dashboard in Einstein Analytics. It contained 5 charts, all from the same datasource, and they all faceted between one another when selections were made. I was asked to change the top chart-- a line graph showing opportunity creation by week-- and make it a stacked bar chart showing the same thing, but broken out by opportunity creator. Now that chart will no longer broadcast its selections to the other charts. If I click on one of the bars, it gets highlighted but nothing else happens. Everything else still works fine. If I make a selection in chart 2, every other chart (including the one I edited) gets filtered by the selection. Everything is from the same datasource, and everything has send/receive facets turned on. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: This could be caused by the columnMap in the widget section. Would you mind posting the JSON to the step, as well as the widget(s) that references that step.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done any changes in SAQL means if you have added any field or removed then check that  the field names are in the same order as in  group statement and foreach statement.
if not put them in same order and then update your step now faceting may work